# Parse unlabeled JSON String into java objects

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string below that I have to parse into java objects. The challenge is the values are not labeled and also there's a collection that's not labeled with each set of values. Please assist or refer to similar examples.

```
{
"body": {
    "records": [
        ["567567/0001", "1499669323", "2806", "676768775", "258596", [
            ["collection/Coin", "AZR", "456.65", "0"]
        ]],
        ["456456/0001", "1499669327", "2806", "6767687565", "252256", [
            ["collection", "AZR", "3940.00", "13"],
            ["collection/Coin", "AZR", "89.63", "0"]
        ]],
        ["354645/0001", "1499669330", "2806", "6767687878", "25452212", [
            ["collection", "AZR", "3940.00", "13"],
            ["collection/Coin", "AZR", "125.36", "0"]
        ]],
        ["4654/0001", "1499669333", "2806", "676768787", "2514785", [
            ["collection", "AZR", "4560.00", "21"],
            ["collection/Coin", "AZR", "987.25", "0"]
        ]]
    ]
},
"responseCode": 0,
"responseMsg": "OK"
}
```

The classes I want to parse the JSON string into are below

```
public class Record {
    private String cdmId;
    private Integer transactionNumber;
    private String collectorUserNumber;
    private String collectionStartTime;
    private String sealNumber;

    private List<CollectionType> collection;

    // getters and setters
}
```

CollectionType Class

```
public class CollectionType {

    private String type;
    private String currency;
    private Double totalAmount;
    private Integer totalPcs;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: which json library are you using ? Or json is in string form ?

Comment: I have used gson before but I'm willing to use any tool that will work.

Comment: You can read body and records json key then after you can iterate array and on each element you check that is it array(`collection/coin, etc`) if yes then add it to new field. As per this you can create custom class and set data accordingly. Is there any expected structure you're looking for in Java ?

Comment: No specific structure, just to be able to parse this format of JSON into a java object to persist to the DB.

Comment: Can you post Java classes to which you would like to parse this JSON?

Comment: @AdrianFarmadin I have updated the post with the classes.

Comment: weird structure, I'm assuming you dont have control over it?

Comment: @AyushGupta I don't, it's a web service response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GSON you have three options how to parse your object as described in [UserGuide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-collection-with-objects-of-arbitrary-types).

> 1. Use Gson's parser API (low-level streaming parser or the DOM parser JsonParser) to parse the array elements and then use
>      Gson.fromJson() on each of the array elements.This is the preferred
>      approach. Here is an example that demonstrates how to do this.
> 2. Register a type adapter for Collection.class that looks at each of the array members and maps them to appropriate objects. The
>      disadvantage of this approach is that it will screw up deserialization
>      of other collection types in Gson.
> 3. Register a type adapter for MyCollectionMemberType and use fromJson() with Collection.

I implemented option 3. a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).

**Message class** to contain whole message.

```java
public class Message {
    private Body body;
    private int responseCode;
    private String responseMsg;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Body class** contains records

```java
public class Body {
    private List<Record> records;

    public Body() {
        records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    }

    public void addRecod(Record record) {
        records.add(record);
    }

    public List<Record> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }
}
```

**Record and CollectionType class** is the same as you posted.

**RecordAdapter class** to parse your custom collection.

```java
public class RecordAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Record> {

    @Override
    public Record read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
             reader.nextNull();
             return null;
        }
        Record record = new Record();
        // read array representing a record
        reader.beginArray();
        record.setCdmId(reader.nextString());
        record.setTransactionNumber(Integer.valueOf(reader.nextString()));
        record.setCollectorUserNumber(reader.nextString());
        record.setCollectionStartTime(reader.nextString());
        record.setSealNumber(reader.nextString());
        // read array containing CollectionType objects
        reader.beginArray();
        while(reader.hasNext()) {
            // read array containing single CollectionTyoe object
            reader.beginArray();
            CollectionType collectionType = new CollectionType();
            collectionType.setType(reader.nextString());
            collectionType.setCurrency(reader.nextString());
            collectionType.setTotalAmount(reader.nextDouble());
            collectionType.setTotalPcs(reader.nextInt());
            record.addCollectionType(collectionType);
            // read end of array containing single CollectionTyoe object
            reader.endArray();
        }
        // read end of array containing CollectionType
        reader.endArray();
        // read end of array representing a record
        reader.endArray();
        return record;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter arg0, Record arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Main method** to try it out

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<Your JSON string goes here>";
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Record.class, new RecordAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    Message message = gson.fromJson(input, Message.class);
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

**GSON dependency**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, which version of Gson jar should I get for this? some methods are not recognized by my Gson which is 2.2.2

Comment: I used version 2.8.2. Can you upgrade to this version or do you need solution for 2.2.2?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a million. @AdrianFarmadin